# Appium iOS driver can't send keys to UIATextField

Tags: ios, selenium, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

I am using Appium 1.4.13, java-client-3.3.0.jar, selenium standalone server 2.48.2 with IntelliJ.

I want to enter a value to UIATextField, which is a numberpicker. I read a tutorial and it suggested:

```
(MobileElement) iosDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATextField")).sendKeys("abcdef");
```

but this didn't work: it just opened a native numberpicker from iOS

Another suggestion is to use setValue for java client 2.2.0:

```
(MobileElement) iosDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATextField")).setValue("abcdef");
```

But setValue method is not there anymore.

So I have a workaround like below and it works:

```
(MobileElement) iosDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATextField")).click;
iosDriver.scrollToExact("abcdef");
//click confirm
```

My questions:

- setValue and sendKeyEvents are not available anymore?
- is there a better way to enter a value and confirm it?

Thanks

This is what I got from Appium Inspector when I run

```
(MobileElement) iosDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATextField")).sendKeys("170");
```

[image]

Comment: By inspector screenshot I meant the layout image using `find` icon you can see on the UI on the action bar of this (4th from left)

Comment: @nullpointer: thank you for your time, I managed to make it work with setValue. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setValue changed to be only valid for IOSElement. Cast your element accordingly and it should work.
Ex: `(IOSElement) iosDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATextField")).setValue("abcdef");`

Source: https://github.com/appium/java-client/blob/master/src/main/java/io/appium/java_client/ios/IOSElement.java

Answer (score 0):

Your initial code with appium 3.3.0 java-client should work just that your input is slight incorrect. A small note on that, a number picker has a regex defined to get an input of Integer type so you can better try sending it a numeral input. Try this, shall help :

```
(MobileElement) iosDriver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIATextField")).sendKeys("12"); //sending an integer value
```

Comment: I tried with Integer, but I still got the same problem: I opened the numberpicker and stayed like this until timeout

Comment: Yeah, it was my workaround in my question: I could click on this textfield, then numberpicker shown up, and I used method scrollToExact("12"), and confirmed. It worked. But I would like to know why I can't use sendKeys, it's strange, since all tutorials I read, always suggested sendKeys

Comment: yeah better way to do that is sendKeys indeed, could you share the screenshot of the appium inspector with the `UIATextField` selected

Comment: oh, now it works with sendKeys, but in a strange way: it entered number value "170" outside of textfield and kind of destroyed the app layout, and the numberpicker still shown up. Appium inspector was in green text and passed the action. Updated my question

Comment: a screenshot of the app form appium inspector would be helpful to look into this

Comment: Uploaded screenshot, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I am working on Xamrin app and Appium iOS driver was not able to send keys to UIATextField using @iOSXCUITFindBy.Though on Android same function was working fine.

I modified the function to first make a click and with this I was able to enter username and password in the webview.

```
public void enterUsername(String userName)

        {
            this.userName.click();
            this.userName.sendKeys(userName);
        }
```